# Change color of a paragraph containing aligned equations

Tags: spacing, color, paragraphs, vertical-spacing

I would like to color a paragraph in blue. As my text contains some equations, I followed the advice given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451289/153361). However, I get extra vertical space when the paragraph ends with an align environment, as shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
{ \color{blue}This is is a paragraph in blue. It contains the equation
\begin{align*}
a & = b + c - 2c\\
&= b - c.
\end{align*}
}

This is a new paragraph in black.
\end{document}
```

[image]

What is the best approach for coloring a paragraph without creating any extra space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(At least with PDFLaTeX) `\color{…}` results in a *whatsit* and is therefore horizontal material. Unfortunately switching back to the previous color at the end of a group also needs a whatsit. So in your case, there is an extra paragraph after the `\end{align*}` caused by switching of the color. My suggestion is to avoid the group and explicitly switch to `\normalcolor` at the beginning of the next paragraph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\color{blue}%
This is is a paragraph in blue. It contains the equation
\begin{align*}
  a & = b + c - 2c\\
    &= b - c.
\end{align*}

\normalcolor
This is a new paragraph in black.
\end{document}
```

[image: no extra paragraph]

An alternative would be to use LuaLaTeX and [package `luacolor`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luacolor):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}

\begin{document}

{\color{blue}%
  This is is a paragraph in blue. It contains the equation
  \begin{align*}
    a & = b + c - 2c\\
      &= b - c.
  \end{align*}}

This is a new paragraph in black.
\end{document}
```

With `luacolor` colors are not longer whatsits (and therefore horizontal material) but node attributes. One more advantage of using LuaLaTeX.

One more alternative would be to add a `\par` after the end of the `align*` but before the end of the group, because the color code tries to avoid such issues in vertical mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

{\color{blue}%
  This is is a paragraph in blue. It contains the equation
  \begin{align*}
    a & = b + c - 2c\\
      &= b - c.
  \end{align*}\par}

This is a new paragraph in black.
\end{document}
```